# Command line BitTorrent client with UDP trackers support

Tags: software-recommendation, bittorrent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there bittorrent software that runs in a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65387/is-there-bittorrent-software-that-runs-in-a-terminal)

I tried btdownloadcurses and while it works fine for most of the torrents, it seems to trip over ones where UDP is employed to track the sources.

The messages I am getting are:

```
Problem connecting to tracker - ('url error', 'unknown url type', 'udp', 'udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80
```

So are there any other command line clients with UDP support?

Comment: why is is closed? the alleged duplicate does not address my issue with UDP trackers specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two packages should be suitable

## [aria2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aria2) [image: Install aria2]

## [rtorrent](http://packages.ubuntu.com/rtorrent) [image: Install rtorrent]

Answer (score 1):

[rtorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtorrent) should support this protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Try rtorrent. Check out the tutorial [here](http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2007/05/02/howto-use-rtorrent-like-a-pro/) if you don't enjoy browsing through manpages.