# Is there BitTorrent software that runs in a terminal?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, bittorrent

I want to deploy it on my VPS server to download resources quickly.

This could save me a lot of time since some resources are in a foreign country,

Comment: What do you mean by "some resource are in foreign country, so use this could reduce my time."?

Comment: @N.N., he probably means that his remote server has access to more resources (bandwidth, probably) so he can download faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Torrent client for the command-line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29872/torrent-client-for-the-command-line)

Answer (score 103):

## Transmission

The default BitTorrent client of Ubuntu Desktop, **Transmission**, has [a command line interface](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/HeadlessUsage) (which is not installed by default, the package is `transmission-daemon`). The daemon can be setup so that it may be interacted with through the terminal and through a web interface.

Transmission is a good bittorrent client because:

- It's lightweight with either interface.
- It's stable, never had it crashing.
- It's easy to understand.
- It has function expected of a modern bittorrent client, e.g. local peer discovery, full encryption, and support for DHT, µTP, PEX and magnet links.

For more info on its features, see this [page](http://www.transmissionbt.com/about/).

Comment: Do mention that you'd need to install `transmission-cli` before you can use it in Terminal. The regular `transmission-gtk` package does not include the CLI. Not to mention there is `transmission-daemon` package as well.

Comment: @Oxwivi the transmission-cli is auto downloaded in Ubuntu 15.04 if the transmission-daemon is installed as described above.

Comment: `transmission-cli` seems to work on its own.

Comment: Note `transmission-cli` command is deprecated and now the command `transmission-remote` is encouraged.

Comment: `sudo apt install transmission-cli` works fine for me

Answer (score 60):

## [rTorrent](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent)[image: software-center image]

[image: rTorrent screenshot]

I have written a detailed tutorial about rTorrent, including its installation and configuration. Check it out [here](http://harbhag.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/tutorial-using-rtorrent-on-linux-like-a-pro/) or see the official [user guide](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/User-Guide).

### rTorrent's pros

- lightweight
- ultra-fast downloading speed
- very effective BitTorrent traffic encryption
- supported by all the private trackers
- very customizable

### rTorrent's cons

- might be difficult to set up (configuration file, no GUI), [example config file](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/CONFIG-Template) for beginners

Comment: Note that rtorrent 0.9.7+ *can* run as a daemon without screen or tmux

Answer (score 31):

## aria2c [image: install aria2c]

A CLI downloader supporting HTTP, FTP, and Torrents.

To download a torrent:

`aria2c file.torrent`

You can also point it to a remote torrent file `http://some web site here.com/file.torrent` so you don't need to download the torrent file first.

Also note you can disable file allocation with this flag: `--file-allocation=none`.

Aria2c also supports parallel downloading on HTTP.    Use the `-j` flag to determine how many threads.  For 3 concurrent downloads of a single HTTP file see the following example:

`aria2c -j 3    website.com/file.rar`

Comment: I tried most of the solutions here and this was the only one that worked with the format of torrent file I had

Answer (score 29):

## Deluge [image: deluge install]

[Deluge](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/About) is a fully featured, yet lightweight torrent client that is written in Python and utilises [libtorrent(rasterbar)](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/features.html) C++ library at its core.

- Standalone or [Thinclient](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient) mode (split core/ui) to enable connecting to daemon (*deluged*) running remotely or in the background.
- Multiple user-interfaces, supports access from most platforms:

  - GTK UI

    [image]
  - Web UI

    [image]
  - Console UI

    [image]
- Many [Plugins](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins) and application extensions
- Supports all the usual bittorrent client functions: DHT, LPD, PEX, UPNP, Encryption, Proxy, etc.

Comment: The best bit about deluge is you can run the background process on the remote server and the GTK interface on your local machine.

Comment: @caveman_dick: yeah, good point; although I went to the web interface for that - every computer has a browser installed (as opposed to Deluge clients - I don't think there's one for smartphones), and the UI is very similar to the GTK version.

Comment: @Piskvor Can you please add additional details? Outlining what features set Deluge apart, reasons you like/use it, screenshots of it in action, additional resources, etc?

Comment: @Marco Ceppi♦: All right, I'll round some of that up and edit.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Why not just go to the website? :) http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/About

Comment: @caveman_dick [Because just saying go to this website doesn't really help with the quality of the site](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1872/how-to-run-the-software-recommendation-tag/1874#1874) :)

Comment: Ah ok, I understand why you said that now! :) The only issue with that rule is the fact that the data will become stale when new features are added and screens change.

Comment: @caveman_dick That is occasionally true - however, we have a large community that updates things such as this regularly.

Comment: @jrg: "Occasionally"? That happens all_the_time. This is only beginning to show at SO - from what I've seen, about 40% of links posted in 2008 are now dead. The decay seems to be non-linear: oldest posted links seem to have much higher probability of leading nowhere than newer links.

Comment: @Piskvor Precisely why we shouldn't link to other sites except when needed. If we (ask ubuntu) have the information, then we don't have linkrot.

Comment: There is more to Deluge that could be expanded on here as it easily matches the features of the other clients listed here. Most users rave about the split client/server architecture which makes it perfect for VPS. If I get time I'll edit the question myself.

Answer (score 12):

## Azureus [image: install azureus]

Azureus/Vuse also has a console mode. [disclaimer] I was one of the developers.

To use azureus in console mode, you will need to download a couple of additional libraries from http://svn.vuze.com/public/client/trunk/uis/lib/

- commons-cli.jar
- log4j.jar

If you place these in same the directory as the Vuze jar, you can launch the console ui by running:

```
java -jar Vuze-xxxx.jar --ui=console
```

Inside the CLI, type help to view the commands. A couple of useful commands are:

- show torrents
- add [url]
- start [x]
- stop [x]
- remove [x]

Here is example output from a 'show torrents' command

```
show torrents
> -----
 1 [>] 025.6%   Azureus4.7.0.0.jar (13.26 MB) ETA: 1m 41s
                Speed: 295.1 kB/s / 0 B/s       Amount: 3.56 MB / 0 B   Connections: 11(20) / 0(4)

Total Speed (down/up): 296.6 kB/s / 2.2 kB/s
Transferred Volume (down/up/discarded): 3.56 MB / 0 B / 0 B
Total Connected Peers (seeds/peers): 11 / 0
> -----
```

Take a look at http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Console_UI for more information :-)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Marco. i've done just that. I couldnt include the link to the apt package because I dont have enough rep at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the update, looks great! I've added the link for you :)

Answer (score 8):

I use it all the time :

```
sudo apt-get install bittornado
```

To download torrents :

```
btdownloadcurses --max_uploads 4 --max_upload_rate 32 to_be_downloaded.torrent
```

Comment: This is the simplest to use.

Answer (score 8):

## ctorrent [image: install ctorrent]

There is [a similar question on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570750/wget-like-bittorrent-client-or-library).

The accepted answer there is CTorrent so I thought I should mention it here. The description of ctorrent from packages.debian.org is as follows:

> This application is written in the C++ language and doesn't require
> any graphical component, such as an X server. Original ctorrent's
> upstream has stopped its development and now it's kept updated with
> new releases/bug fixes by a new developer. It's built as a console
> program and it can be even used remotely in a machine that provides
> outside ssh access.

For more info you can visit following sites:
http://packages.debian.org/sid/ctorrent
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctorrent/

there is also an enhanced version of ctorrent which can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/dtorrent/

Answer (score 4):

Try utorrent linux alpha version. Its a headless server which can be controlled from your browser (web UI). http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux.

Comment: [Could you expand your answer to fit the 'Software Recommendations guidelines](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1872/how-to-run-the-software-recommendation-tag/1874#1874)?

Comment: As of now, uTorrent Linux Alpha doesn't run in a terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I use [tget](https://github.com/jeffjose/tget) which is (in the author's words) "wget for torrents".  It allows you do download using torrent files or magnet links.  It is a node.js application.

```
tget 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0403fb4728bd788fbcb67e87d6feb241ef38c75a'
```

To install:

```
npm install -g t-get
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but nobody mentioned [peerflix](https://github.com/mafintosh/peerflix).

Written in JavaScript, works great, super simple to use, has a nice, informative and colored interface.

Most importantly, it supports streaming of video and audio content through VLC (just launch it with the flag `--vlc`).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation without installing anything (if you have node)

```
npx -p webtorrent-cli webtorrent download "magent:..."
```

It's will temporary download the `webtorrent-cli` pakcage, then execute the `webtorretn` commmand to download your torrent.

Answer (score 0):

## You can use [torrent-dl](https://github.com/pigeonburger/torrent-dl)

It was originally based off of `tget`, a tool mentioned [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/847512/1121937), but the project has since significantly diverted from it. `tget` does not offer any configurability (e.g. searching popular torrent sites, customizing what port to use, downloading multiple torrents, etc) so `torrent-dl` adds all of these features.

Example usage (with some of the extra options):

```
torrent-dl -i magnet:?xt=urn:btih:b26c81363ac1a236765385a702aec107a49581b5 --port 43022 --connections 250 --uploadslots 25
```

You can see all the options it offers on it's Github page linked at the top. It is a nodejs application, however you can download standalone binaries (MacOS and Windows binaries are also available) from the releases page on it's Github, meaning no nodejs or npm installation is required.

It can also be installed via `npm`, however:

```
npm install -g torrent-dl
```

**I am the author of this project.**